# Python (v3) Trouble Getting Output

Tags: python

I'm trying to get this program to give me an output that looks like this:

```
Enter a number (-9999 to end):  4
Enter a number (-9999 to end):  -3
Enter a number (-9999 to end): -15
Enter a number (-9999 to end):  0
Enter a number (-9999 to end):  10
Enter a number (-9999 to end):  22
Enter a number (-9999 to end):  -9999


The list of all numbers entered is:
[4, -3, -15, 0, 10, 22]

The dictionary with averages is:
{'AvgPositive': 12.0, 'AvgNonPos': -6.0, 'AvgAllNum': 3.0}
```

This is the code I have so far but it's not working obviously. Any help is appreciated, but please show in code. Mostly I'm having trouble getting the bottom line of "The dictionary with averages is:
{'AvgPositive': 12.0, 'AvgNonPos': -6.0, 'AvgAllNum': 3.0}"

```
def nums():
    values = []
    while -9999 not in values:
        x = int(input("Enter a number (-9999 to end: )"))
        values.append(x)
    values.remove(-9999)
    return values

def allNumAvg(values):
    average = 0
    sum = 0
    for n in values:
        sum = sum + n

    average = sum / len(values)

    return average

def avgNonPos(values):
    return allNumAvg([v for v in values if v<0])

    if int in values < 0:
        x.append(int)

    print(x)

    return average

def posNumAvg(values):
    return allNumAvg([v for v in values if v>0])

    if int in values > 0:
        x.append(int)

    print(x)
input(print("'AvgPositive': ",posNumAvg(nums())),"'AvgNonPos': ",avgNonPos(nums())),"'AvgAllNum': ",allNumAvg(nums())
```

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: It just says: 'AvgPositive': 12.0 How do I get it to print the other averages, for nonPos and allNum?

Comment: Every time you call `nums()` it will ask you to input some numbers. You call it three times on the last line. The return value of `print` is `None`, which you are then passing to the `input` function. I think you are probably expected to create a dictionary of averages and then print it.

Comment: You need to create a variable `numbers = nums()` and pass it to the other functions instead of calling `nums()` repeatedly.

Comment: Can you show me how to do this in the code above, I'm having trouble creating the variable because then it doesn't recognize the first one.

Comment: Show us in your question how it doesn't recognise the first variable. Try a new small piece of code, away from this, and get that working first. Or if you can't get it working, at least it will be a smaller piece of code to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

I think you had somethings miswritten here:

- passing nums() in each function while calling it would make the user enter his numbers again, instead you should make this only once and save the result in a variable and u should then pass that to the functions
- I don't understand the use of an if condition after returning correctly what the function should be returning... I think you were testing something...

for readability I've omitted the if conditions and fixed the print statement you have, I think this is what you were trying to achieve:

```
def nums():
    values = []
    while -9999 not in values:
        x = int(input("Enter a number (-9999 to end: )"))
        values.append(x)
    values.remove(-9999)
    return values


def allNumAvg(values):
    average = 0
    sum = 0
    for n in values:
        sum = sum + n

    average = sum / len(values)

    return average


def avgNonPos(values):
    return allNumAvg([v for v in values if v < 0])



def posNumAvg(values):
    return allNumAvg([v for v in values if v > 0])


values = nums()
print "'AvgPositive': ", posNumAvg(values)
print "'AvgNonPos': ", avgNonPos(values)
print "'AvgAllNum': ", allNumAvg(values)
```

let me know if that was correct or if you need any further functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a version of the code that works as intended (I hope)

```
def nums():
    values = []
    while -9999 not in values:
        x = int(input("Enter a number (-9999 to end: )"))
        values.append(x)
    values.remove(-9999)
    return values


def allNumAvg(values):
    return sum(values) / len(values)


def avgNonPos(values):
    return allNumAvg([v for v in values if v < 0])


def posNumAvg(values):
    return allNumAvg([v for v in values if v > 0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    values = nums()
    print("The list of all numbers entered is:")
    print(values)
    print("The dictionary with averages is:")
    print({'AvgPositive': posNumAvg(values), 'AvgNonPos': avgNonPos(values), 'AvgAllNum': allNumAvg(values)})
```

Things to note:

1: Calling nums() two times (in the code below) means that numbers will be collected two times, which is not desired

```
input(print("'AvgPositive': ",posNumAvg(nums())),"'AvgNonPos': ",avgNonPos(nums())),"'AvgAllNum': ",allNumAvg(nums())
```

In my code example you can see that nums() is called once and are saved in values which is later passed along.

2: The code below in avgNonPos/posNumAvg is dead code. I.e. it is not run, since it exists after the return statement.

```
if int in values > 0:
    x.append(int)
```

3: I cleaned up the allNumAvg(values) function a bit by using the builtin function sum()